# Truffle Test: Using a contract instance as function parameter

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I'm having a function IN A LIB that require a contract as parameter.

```
function createCalendarEntry(uint256 releaseTime,
    SPToken token) public pure returns (CalendarEntry memory) {
    return CalendarEntry(releaseTime, token);
}
```

To test this function im doing:

```
    const spToken = await SPToken.new(token, {from: accounts[1]});
    const cal = await myLib.createCalendarEntry.call(web3.utils.toBN(now), spToken);
```

as error im getting `Error: invalid type (argument="type", value="SPToken", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)`

What should i do to make this `spToken` javascript instance a valid parameter as contract for the function?

Thanks!

Edit: added information that this function is inside a library.

Answer (score 0):

Truffle's contract isn't smart enough to know that a contract has an address

If I remember correctly you have to pass `spToken.address` as the parameter.

```
const spToken = await SPToken.new(token, {from: accounts[1]});
const cal = await myLib.createCalendarEntry.call(web3.utils.toBN(now), spToken.address);
```

Comment: I tried that too and i got the same error.